# I made a mistake by deleting AppData and ProgramData. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows-8, restore

I unfortunately deleted AppData and ProgramData folder from C drive since because I wanted to gain space. This resulted in deleting of all apps from my Windows 8 tiles. Also my Store App is also not responding to reinstall apps.

Is there a way to reset my PC to the original state?

Answer (score 2):

Use the refresh feature of Windows 8:

- Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap `Settings`, and then tap `Change PC settings`.
  (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click `Settings`, and then click `Change PC settings`.)
- Under `PC settings`, tap or click `General`.
- Under `Refresh your PC without affecting your files`, tap or click `Get started`.
- Follow the instructions on the screen.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc

Comment: This will *partially* solve the issue. Best would be to reinstall from a backup but since you're not mentioning that I assume you don't make backups. Consider that a lesson learned. You can reinstall the programs that are still missing after the refresh from their original source (CD, download location), but most data that you deleted will be gone.